# Prove $ \int_0^1 (1+a+a^2\pi^2x^{2a})\sin(\pi x^a)dx = a\pi$ using previous results

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

If $a>0$ prove, 
$$ \int_0^1 \sin(\pi x^a)dx+a\pi\int_0^1 \ x^a\cos(\pi x^a)dx = 0 \tag1$$
$$ \int_0^1 \cos(\pi x^a)dx-a\pi\int_0^1 \ x^a\sin(\pi x^a)dx = -1 \tag2$$
$$ \int_0^1 (1+a+a^2\pi^2x^{2a})\sin(\pi x^a)dx = a\pi\tag3$$
Parts (1) and (2) are ok, using integration by parts on  $ \int_0^1 \sin(\pi x^a)dx$, and $ \int_0^1 \cos(\pi x^a)dx$, respectively.

To illustrate, in (1).,  let $ u = \sin(\pi x^a) \Rightarrow du = a \pi x^{a-1}cos(\pi x^a)dx$, then with $dv = 1dx \Rightarrow v = x$

On integrating by parts, $ \int_0^1 \sin(\pi x^a)dx = [xsin(\pi x^a)]_0^1 -a\pi\int_0^1 x^acos(\pi x^a)dx $, which gives
$ \int_0^1 \sin(\pi x^a)dx = -a\pi\int_0^1 \ x^acos(\pi x^a)dx$
and therefore, $ \int_0^1 \sin(\pi x^a)dx +a\pi\int_0^1 \ x^acos(\pi x^a)dx = 0$\

Same procedure for part (2)., except let $ u = \cos(\pi x^a) \Rightarrow du = -a \pi x^{a-1}sin(\pi x^a)dx$, then with $dv = 1dx \Rightarrow v = x$
Integrating by parts this time leads to the desired result, $ \int_0^1 \cos(\pi x^a)dx$ - $ a\pi\int_0^1 \ x^asin(\pi x^a)dx = -1 $

To prove (3), I believe the previous results are to be used somehow. I have re written (3) as,
$ \int_0^1 (1+a+a^2\pi^2x^{2a})sin(\pi x^a)dx = (1+a)\int_0^1 \sin(\pi x^a)dx + a^2 \pi^2 \int_0^1 x^{2a}\sin(\pi x^a)dx$, and trying to resolve the integral $\int_0^1 x^{2a}\sin(\pi x^a)dx$, with the awkward factor $x^{2a}$.

The first thing I tried was let $u=x^{2a}\Rightarrow du=2ax^{2a-1}dx$

Then $dv= sin(\pi x^a)dx \Rightarrow v=\int sin(\pi x^a)dx$, but because $v$ is an integral, and remains to be if using the result from part (1), I can't integrate this by parts, because I get:

$\int_0^1 x^{2a}\sin(\pi x^a)dx = [x^{2a} \int sin(\pi x^a)dx]_0^1  - \int_0^1 (\int sin(\pi x^a)(2ax^{2a-1})dx)dx$

I have also tried writing the integral as, $\int_0^1 x^{2a}\sin(\pi x^a)dx = \int x^a(x^a \sin(\pi x^a))dx$, then differentiating $x^a \sin(\pi x^a)$, using product rule to give,
$du = a \pi x^{2a-1} \cos(\pi x^a)+ax^{a-1} \sin(\pi x^a)$
Then with $dv=x^adx \Rightarrow v=\frac {x^{a+1}}{a+1}$

Integrating by parts gives the result, $(2a+1)\int x^a(x^a \sin(\pi x^a))dx = -a \pi \int_0^1 x^{3a} \cos(\pi x^a)dx$

Integrating $\int_0^1 x^{3a} \cos(\pi x^a)dx$ by parts by differentiating the product $x^{2a} \cos(\pi x^a)$ and integrating $x^a$ then brings in a term $\int_0^1 x^{4a} \sin(\pi x^a) dx$, which looks to be going the wrong way!

Any fantastic tips to nudge me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Continue with the first result

$$ \int_0^1 \sin(\pi x^a)dx=-a\pi\int_0^1 \ x^a\cos(\pi x^a)dx \tag 1$$
and integrate the RHS by parts
$$ \int_0^1 \sin(\pi x^a)dx=a\pi\left( 1+\int_0^1 a x^a \cos(\pi x^a)dx - a\pi \int_0^1 x^{2a}\sin(\pi x^2)dx\right)\tag2$$
Then, substitute (1) into (2) to arrive at the third result
$$ \int_0^1 (1+a+a^2\pi^2x^{2a})\sin(\pi x^a)dx = a\pi$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I simply did not see the connection from (1). This has helped tremendously!